# How to implement a trial membership using Organic groups?

Tags: rules, users, organic-groups, cron

I work on a Drupal site with the [Organic groups](http://www.drupal.org/project/og) module, where users can `create account`.

When the process for creating an account is finished, users have access to a specific `group` and should have `og role` **Trial member** (automatically assigned) with state **Active**, and this for a limited time period.

After that limited time period is passed, user still has `og role` **Trial member** assigned, but with state **Pending**.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect job to accomplish with the [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Below are the headlines of how you could get this to work ...

## Rule 1 (When user account is created)

- Event: When a new user account is created
- Action:

  1. Grant access to role `Trial member`.
  2. Set some **Date** field value = `expiration date` (cfr. your "limited time").
  3. Set some **State** field value = `Active`.

## Rule 2 (When expired)

- Event: When user logs in
- Condition: if the date indicated in field with `expiration date` is passed.
- Action: Set your **State** field value = `Pending`.

## Recommended video tutorials

#### Rules

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

#### Organic Groups

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Organic Groups](http://www.drupal.org/project/og), then reviewing the amazing set of videos to [Learn Organic Groups](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-organic-groups) might help.

## Other variations

There are other variations to make this work with the [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. E.g. by using 'Rules Scheduler' (= sub-module of Rules) to schedule a variation of "Rule 2", to be executed on your `expiration date`.